# VB.NET published windows app doesn't run

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, publishing

TOOLS:
Windows 10 Pro
Visual Studio 2017 Pro

I created a VB.NET windows app GUI on my desktop computer,
 published it, 
copied the publish\ directory to a new target laptop, 
logged into laptop and ran publish > setup.exe
it asked me to "install" and I said YES,
and app started, but hung, never displaying the GUI.
My app has two .DLL's of mine, but they are not in the publish\ directory.

I made a HELLO WORLD on original desktop, published, and it ran ok at laptop.

Comment: define *not working*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.  The target laptop needed installation of drivers from a vendor of some 3rd party middleware used in the app.

So, the packaging software wasn't smart enough to tell me the problem, and its error correction response was to just end without any error message.

Answer (score 0):

All of your dlls need to be distributed with your application.

Try manually move your dlls in the same folder of .exe file on target machine: if it works simply rebuild your setup incuding these dlls as [dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx).